# Different ways to write a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, systems-of-equations

Suppose we have this linear system of equations:

$${ \begin{cases}{2x_1+x_2=3} \\ {-x_1+2x_2+x_3=2} \\ {-x_2+2x_3+x_4=2} \\ {-x_3+2x_4+x_5=2} \\ {-x_4+2x_5=1}\end{cases} }$$
I mostly saw it was written as :
$${ \begin{cases}
2x_1&+x_2&&&&=3 \\
-x_1&+2x_2&+x_3&&&=2 \\
&-x_2&+2x_3&+x_4&&=2 \\
&&-x_3&+2x_4+x_5&&=2 \\
&&&-x_4+2x_5&&=1
\end{cases} }$$
Which one is more common and better way to write this system? is it really important to write like second case ?

Comment: Hi, I wrote the second one because, in my humble opinion, the second one just looks clearer. I think it also gives a slight hint on how to start solving the problem. When you have the different unknowns aligned like that, it's clearer how to proceed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the edit on my previous question :) it caused me to think about this subject.

Comment: Most often such a system of linear equations is rewritten to *matrix* form $Ax=b$, and for that, 2. can be viewed as an intermediate step.